# Property Wrappers With Generic (Optional) User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift, generics, nsuserdefaults

> **With due reference:**
>
> https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#user-defaults

We've started to use property wrappers for the UserDefaults, it works seamlessly with non-optional properties.

However, setting nil of an optional property crashes with:

> [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object  as an
>   NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key "someKeyThatWeSet"
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
>   list object null for key "someKeyThatWeSet"'

The code below can be tested on Playground directly:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct C2AppProperty<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

struct C2User {
    @C2AppProperty("userID", defaultValue: nil)
    public static var publicUserID: String?
}

print(C2User.publicUserID)
C2User.publicUserID = "edusta"
print(C2User.publicUserID)
C2User.publicUserID = nil
print(C2User.publicUserID)
```

> **Expected:**
>
> nil
>
> Optional<"edusta">
>
> nil
>
> **Found:**
>
> nil
>
> Optional<"edusta">
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

**What I've tried so far:**

```
set {
    // Comparing non-optional value of type 'T' to nil always returns false.
    if newValue == nil {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: combinedKey)
    } else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: combinedKey)
    }
}
```

What kind of a check is needed here to catch that newValue is `nil`? Or an `Optional<nil>`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T
    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T, userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        self.userDefaults = userDefaults
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let value = userDefaults.object(forKey: key) else {
                return defaultValue
            }

            return value as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue as? OptionalProtocol, value.isNil() {
                userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
            } else {
                userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate protocol OptionalProtocol {
    func isNil() -> Bool
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
    func isNil() -> Bool {
        return self == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'm curious whether there is another elegant solution, but this works as well. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to solve this problem for several hours, it's the best way I've found.

Comment: There is one other way. This is interesting approach but your getter will ignore `defaultValue` for optional types and will return `nil` if there is no value in `UserDefaults` for the `key`. The case is described in more details in https://dev.to/kodelit/userdefaults-property-wrapper-issues-solutions-4lk9 discussion is appreciated

Comment: Yes, you are right, I edited my getter, now it works for your case.

Comment: This code crashes... How does it work exactly?

Comment: This code works for me in a production code in 10+ applications, so I don't know why it crashes for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michcio for providing the solution，

If we read property very frequently, the following code **may have better performance**. Use storage property can save value in memory, it won't be read value from disk every time.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct ReadOptimizeStorage<T> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T
    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

    init(key: String, defaultValue: T, userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        self.userDefaults = userDefaults
        
        wrappedValue = userDefaults.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
     }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        didSet {
            if let value =  wrappedValue as? OptionalProtocol, value.isNil() {
                userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
            } else {
                userDefaults.set(wrappedValue, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}


fileprivate protocol OptionalProtocol {
    func isNil() -> Bool
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
    func isNil() -> Bool {
        return self == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a tiny spm package inspired by the ripples answers above:

https://github.com/mezhevikin/userdefault.git

```
import UserDefault

extension UserDefaults {
    
    // Optional property
    @UserDefault("login", .standard)
    static var login: String?
    
    // Property with default value
    @UserDefault("isDarkMode", false)
    static var isDarkMode: Bool
}
UserDefaults.login = "mezhevikin"
UserDefaults.isDarkMode = true
```